# Android DataBinding

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

I am trying data binding for Android. My app is calling an API and storing the result in an object model. I want to display the contents of the model in an activity. My API call is made on the click of a button. The code is as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String apiKey = "somekey";
APIInterface apiService = null;
EditText editText;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    apiService = APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Result", "Inside onclick");
            String text = editText.getText().toString();
            Call<APIResultModel> call = apiService.getSearchResult(text, apiKey);
            Log.d("Result", "Before enqueue");
            call.enqueue(new Callback<APIResultModel>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<APIResultModel> call, Response<APIResultModel> response) {
                    if (response.body().results != null) {
                        List<ProductModel> productModelList = response.body().results;
                        if (productModelList != null && productModelList.size() > 0) {
                            final ProductModel productModel = productModelList.get(0);
                            ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(MainActivity.this, R.layout.activity_main);
                            binding.setProduct(productModel);
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<APIResultModel> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
            Log.d("Result", "After enqueue")
        }
    });

}
}
```

The contents of the XML file are as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<data>
    <variable
        name="product"
        type="com.mvvm.prakh.mvvmarchitecture.models.ProductModel" />
</data>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.mvvm.prakh.mvvmarchitecture.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Submit" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/brand_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@{product.brandName}"
        android:hint="Brand name comes here" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/brand_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@{product.productName}"
        android:hint="Product name comes here" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My model is as follows:

```
package com.mvvm.prakh.mvvmarchitecture.models;

import android.databinding.BaseObservable;
import android.databinding.Bindable;

import com.android.databinding.library.baseAdapters.BR;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class ProductModel extends BaseObservable{
@SerializedName("brandName")
public String brandName;
@SerializedName("productName")
public String productName;

public ProductModel(String brandName, String productName) {
    this.brandName = brandName;
    this.productName = productName;
}

@Bindable
public String getBrandName() {
    return brandName;
}

public void setBrandName(String brandName) {
    this.brandName = brandName;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.brandName);
}

@Bindable
public String getProductName() {
    return productName;
}

public void setProductName(String productName) {
    this.productName = productName;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.productName);
}
}
```

I have put a Log.d statement inside the `onClick()`, on the first click it gives the output but for the subsequent clicks I am not getting an output. Seems to me that the click is disabled after I have populated the fields using data binding.

Logcat output:

```
02-04 14:53:30.040 16778-16778/com.mvvm.prakh.mvvmarchitecture D/Result: Inside on click
02-04 14:53:30.135 16778-16778/com.mvvm.prakh.mvvmarchitecture D/Result: Before enqueue
02-04 14:53:30.151 16778-16778/com.mvvm.prakh.mvvmarchitecture D/Result: After enqueue
```

So on clicking the button I can see the data being populated as a result of the API but on clicking the button further it becomes unresponsive. Is there something I am missing here which resets the condition to allow clicking the button again?

Comment: Could you share adb log?

Comment: @SungMinLee added the same.

Comment: simply add some `Log.d` stuff inside `onClick` method (when it starts and when it ends) and watch the `logcat`

Comment: @pskink added the logcat

Comment: i dont see any `Log.d` calls

Comment: @pskink Oh! Sorry for that. Edited the code

Comment: add it also right before and right after `call.enqueue(...)`

Comment: @pskink Did the same.

Comment: ok its because tou call `DataBindingUtil.setContentView` inside `Callback.onResponse` method

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several issues considering the Android Data Binding. All togther you should setup the binding at the beginning of `onCreate()` and use from that time on. If you don't have a reference to it, you could find it with `DataBindingUtil` again. No need for `findViewById()` or resetting the layout in `onResponse()`.

```
DataBindingUtil.setContentView(MainActivity.this, R.layout.activity_main)
```

This creates new instances of your views and non of these you setup thereafter. Instead you should implement it like the following.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(MainActivity.this, R.layout.activity_main);
    apiService = APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);

    binding.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String text = binding.editText.getText().toString();
            Call<APIResultModel> call = apiService.getSearchResult(text, apiKey);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<APIResultModel>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<APIResultModel> call, Response<APIResultModel> response) {
                    if (response.body().results != null) {
                        List<ProductModel> productModelList = response.body().results;
                        if (productModelList != null && productModelList.size() > 0) {
                            binding.setProduct(productModelList.get(0));
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<APIResultModel> call, Throwable t) {
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, could you tell me why the button click be disabled after clicking it once?

Comment: Is it still an issue? Before you just removed the button from the layout; maybe overlaid it with the new layout you inflated `onResponse()`. So you got a new button and didn't set it up.

Answer (score 0):

After you call DataBindingUtil.setContentView, the onclicklistener will be reset.
This is my databinding demo project,hope will help you.
https://github.com/LenaYan/AndroidMVVM

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code little bit

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String apiKey = "somekey";
APIInterface apiService = null;
ActivityMainBinding binding;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(MainActivity.this,
R.layout.activity_main);
apiService = APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class); 
binding.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("Result", "Inside onclick");
        String text = editText.getText().toString();
        Call<APIResultModel> call = apiService.getSearchResult(text, apiKey);
        Log.d("Result", "Before enqueue");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<APIResultModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<APIResultModel> call, Response<APIResultModel> response) {
                if (response.body().results != null) {
                    List<ProductModel> productModelList = response.body().results;
                    if (productModelList != null && productModelList.size() > 0) {
                        final ProductModel productModel = productModelList.get(0);
                         binding.setProduct(productModel);
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<APIResultModel> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });
        Log.d("Result", "After enqueue")
    }
});
}
}
```

Put NotifyChanges() rather than notifyPropertyChanged(int fieldId) in setter for pojo .
 [Difference you can find from the link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BaseObservable.html)

and tutorial from this link [enter link description here](https://android.jlelse.eu/implement-android-data-binding-library-in-your-android-app-part-2-d30c717b1b63)